# how to solve cannot read property 0 of undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have already tried many of the solutions on Stack Overflow but none of them have worked in my case. I'm just stuck on this little parsing thing in this ajax call. 
My json looks like this:

```
{
  "DailyCohorts":[
    {
      "transDate":"2017-10-01",
      "newUsers":"9",
      "CustomerAddedDate":"2017-10-01",
      "UserCount":"5"
    }, 
    //...
  ]
}
```

and this is my for loop where I'm trying to take out values

```
 function dailyCohort(){

  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://com/sp/cohort.php",

   success: function(data){    

      console.log("json",data);
      console.log("data length",data.length);

    for(i=0; i< data.DailyCohorts.length; i++)
    {
       console.log(data.DailyCohorts[i].transDate);
    }

    }, 
     beforeSend: function() {
        $("#w-cohort-loader").show()
    },
    complete: function() {
        $("#w-cohort-loader").hide();
    },

    error: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    } 
    }); 
}
```

Please help me with this, thanks in advance

Comment: Array indexes run from 0 up to `length - 1`. Also that JSON you posted is not valid; it starts with `{` but ends with `]`.

Comment: Seeing the error in title, `data` seems to be `undefined`.

Comment: sorry actually I only posted a line. there is a closing braces.

Comment: Do a `console.log(data)` and see if it shows `undefined`.

Comment: no it does not.

Answer (score 3):

You should be accessing `DailyCohorts` property of your JSON object. `DailyCohorts` is the array which you should be looping through and getting each item.

```
success: function(data){ 
   for(i=0; i< data.DailyCohorts.length; i++)
   {
       console.log(data.DailyCohorts[i].transDate);
   }
}
```

or if you use  `$.each` to loop through the `DailyCohorts` array

```
$.each(data.DailyCohorts,function(index,item){
    console.log(item.transDate);
});
```

It is always a good idea to check whether this proeprty exist before trying to access it.

```
if(data.DailyCohorts)
{
    for(i=0; i< data.DailyCohorts.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(data.DailyCohorts[i].transDate);
    }
}
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/qawuhujeco/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working js fiddle for your reference.

Comment: I already tried for loop like this, before posting the query, it didn't solve.

Comment: It should work. Here is a working jsfiddle  http://jsbin.com/mafoyuguyo/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I don't understand why it is not working in my code. this is my error    cohortRetention.js:68 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: May be you have some other script error in the page(check your browser dev tools) ,or may be your ajax call response is not the one you posted in the question (or that structure). do a console.log(data) and see if it matches with the one you posted in the question. browser dev tools (F12 on chrome) will help you identify the issues .

Comment: So what is the problem now ? Are you getting any script errors ? If your JSON is same as what you posted, that code should work fine.